# Getter or assignement for private property?

Tags: android, kotlin

Usually when working with LiveData in ViewModel class we have something like this:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _textLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val textLiveData: LiveData<String>
        get() = _textLiveData
}
```

But we can achieve the same result like this:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _textLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val textLiveData: LiveData<String> = _textLiveData
}
```

I was always wondering what is the best approach. Usually I use the second example from above.

Any thoughts recommendation about this will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because both properties are immutable, there's no practical difference between these two approaches. However, they do work slightly differently under the hood.

We can see the difference by comparing the Kotlin code to Java. The first approach, using a getter, is equivalent to the following Java code:

```java
public final class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
   private final MutableLiveData _textLiveData = new MutableLiveData();

   public final LiveData getTextLiveData() {
      return _textLiveData;
   }
}
```

The second approach, using a property with a backing field, is equivalent to this Java code:

```java
public final class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
   private final MutableLiveData _textLiveData = new MutableLiveData();

   private final LiveData textLiveData = _textLiveData

   public final LiveData getTextLiveData() {
      return textLiveData;
   }
}
```

As you can see, the inclusion of the backing field means there's slightly more code. The value is stored in two separate fields instead of one, and one of the fields is never used. In practice, this won't have any memory or performance cost big enough to be worth worrying about. But I still prefer the simpler `get()` version, because I like knowing the underlying result is "cleaner".

If the property was mutable, the getter approach would be your only option. Using two separate backing fields would mean that changes to the underlying `_textLiveData` field would not be reflected in the public `textLiveData` property.

---

In future, the Kotlin team plan to add a dedicated syntax for these kinds of properties, so that it won't be necessary to declare two separate properties at all.

You can find the discussion in the Kotlin issue tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14663.

Based on the current discussions, the way your example code might look under the new proposals is this:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val textLiveData: LiveData<String>
        field = MutableLiveData() // ❌ not real Kotlin code... yet!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Getter** - The first one you specify is using a `Getter`. When you use a getter to provide access to a private property, you'll have more control over how the property is accessed and modified. You can also add custom logic to the getter if needed.

This is often used when you want to expose the property with some additional checks or transformations. For example, you might want to convert the data type or apply some validation before exposing it, etc.

**2. Direct Assignment** - The second one is a `Direct Assignment`. You can use this if you simply want to provide external access to the private property without any additional logic or checks, this is simply concise and clear.

This is often used because it is straightforward, especially if no need for custom logic or validation.

---

The second one you are using is much better in your case if you don't need or not adding any custom logic or transformation to the `textLiveData`, its simple and straightforward. But if you do need some extra custom logic or transformation, the first one which is the `Getter` becomes more valuable.

Comment: Thank you for you response. I understand for what are used accessor methods :) .The question was about the `get()` without customization vs direct assignment. In official docs it's used the first method